# Restrict certain endpoints/paths in Dropwizard

Tags: ssl, certificate, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard for making RESTful web services and I currently have two endpoints with different paths and I'd like to restrict one of them to only allow connections with SSL certificates while keeping the other one unsecure. I assume that this is done in my .yml file but I cannot seem to find how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is not possible to fix using just DropWizard.
The serverconnectors (either HTTPS or plain HTTP) can be configured through the yml file as you said, but in the application itself, there is no distinction between requests that were SSL and those that were not.

One way to solve this would be to introduce another SSL-terminator (like Apache httpd or nginx) in front of Dropwizard, and proxying requests to specific URLs after terminating SSL.

That would look like this:

```
https://mysite/* -> apache httpd -> proxied to http://localhost:8080/dropwizard/secured/*
http://mysite/* -> apache httpd -> proxied to http://localhost:8080/dropwizard/unsecured/*
```

Comment: I solved it in a similar way, by using a `Filter` subclass to restrict the access when using the insecure port.